# lsof open files count not same

Tags: linux, awk, lsof

I want to know the count of opened files of each process so I use the lsof command with:

```
lsof -n | awk '{print $2}'|sort |uniq -c |sort -nr| more
```

And I found a process with pid `"934"` opened 11374 files but when I use

```
lsof -p 934 | wc -l
```

it is wired that the result shows that it only opened 122 files.

The following images shows the command I used.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why the two counts are different?

### Reason one:

`lsof` generates a header, it was counted in your `lsof -p xxx`, however, in your `awk` filtering, it was filtered out (header has no `$2==pid`), so the count must be different. However we see the difference is >>1, so reason two comes.

### Reason two: (the main reason)

`lsof` will default always output thread id (`TID` read man page for details). However, if you add `-p xxx`, only process opened files are listed, without TID.

If you want to prove it, try this two lines:

```
lsof -p somePid|wc -l
```

And

```
lsof|awk '$2==somePid||NR==1'|wc -l
```

The output should be same.

You should customize the output format, to reach your goal.

Comment: in man lsof , 'TID' is not 'thread id' but 'task id' , I'm not sure what it means. And "lsof|awk '$2==somePid||NR==1'|wc -l" still not equal to "lsof -p somePid|wc -l
"

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199479/discrepancy-with-lsof-command-when-trying-to-get-the-count-of-open-files-per-pro/199487#199487?newreg=268daccaeebc408a9adc28483b15d84d

Answer (score -1):

```
lsof -n | awk '{Count[$2]++} END{asorti( Count, PIDs);for( pid in PIDs) print pid "\t" PIDs[pid]}'
```

try this, avoiding several subshell and only 1 awk behind your lsof

For non gnu sed (where `asorti` is missing)

```
lsof -n | awk '{Count[$2]++} END{for( pid in Count) print pid "\t" Count[pid]}' | sort
```

Comment: idk why you got downvoted but you should state that's gawk-specific due to `asorti()`.